# looping exist files in the map folder

Tags: c#

I am trying to validate  when the user click `btnCheck`. This will trigger `isAllRequiredFilesExist` . The process need to check against all the file names specified `fileNameRequired`. When the file is not found, then terminate the process and display error message otherwise the process will continue until all file name being checked and exist in the map folder.

Current code that I have, it only iterate once then stop. I believe something wrong with my loop statement in `isAllRequiredFilesExist`. The code should not hit the `validateData()` until all file names being check and exist

Could anybody advise if any better way to this. Thank you

```
protected void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Message = string.Empty;
    string pathDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/");
    try
    {
        //need to check all file names exist before execute ValidateData()
        if (isAllRequiredFilesExist()) 
        {
            validateData();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Message = ex.Message;

    }

}

/// <summary>
/// Check if all required data Exist
/// If one required file is missing then notify the user and end the process otherwise it will loop until all names in filenameRequired.

/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool isAllRequiredFilesExist()
{
    string pathDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/");
    string[] fileNameRequired = { "test1.txt", "test2.txt", "test3.txt" };
    //Check if all the required file exist in the folder
    foreach (string names in fileNameRequired)
    {
        //Loop through the folder
        //if there is a missing file then notified the user 

        foreach (string fileNameToCheck in Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathDirectory, names, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            if (!File.Exists(fileNameToCheck))
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Missing file: " + names;
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `isAllRequiredFilesExist` - it returns true if the single file exists. Change it like this:

```
public bool isAllRequiredFilesExist()
{
    string pathDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/");
    string[] fileNameRequired = { "test1.txt", "test2.txt", "test3.txt" };
    //Check if all the required file exist in the folder
    foreach (string names in fileNameRequired)
    {
        //Loop through the folder
        //if there is a missing file then notified the user 

        foreach (string fileNameToCheck in Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathDirectory, names, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            if (!File.Exists(fileNameToCheck))
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Missing file: " + names;
                return false;
            }    
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

So if any given file is missing it will return false and if all the required files are there - it will return true after the loop.

Also [`EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd383571%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return a collection of existing files, so you dont need to check it once again with `File.Exists` - just check the size of collection like:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathDirectory, names, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
if (!files.Any())
{
   lblMessage.Text = "Missing file: " + names;
   return false;
}
```

But its up to you :)

Comment: You are welcome. Also, if there is no real directories under /UploadFiles/ and everithing just in there you can end up without EnumerateFiles and check with more readable File.Exists

Answer (score 0):

take both the return statements out in your most inner loop

```
if (!File.Exists(fileNameToCheck))
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Missing file: " + names;
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
```

Instead of return, do something else, then at the end, make the return
Cause, once you return, you exit out the method with the return value. In your case, you don't want to return true yet, not till all names are checked